# React Dev Tools shows 'Anonymous' for every component in the Components tab

Tags: reactjs, anonymous, react-devtools, react-with-styles

In Browser, React-Devtools, in the Components tab 'Context.Privder ...Anonymous' shows throughout rather than each Component name....

[image]

I understand that is to do with the way each component is exported.
In my app I have components which would typically look like...

```
class MyClassComponent extends Component {
// ...code..
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(withStyles(styles)(MyClassComponent));
```

or mostly with just 'withStyles'...

```
class MyOtherClassComponent extends Component {
// ...code..
}
export default withStyles(styles)(MyOtherClassComponent)
```

How can i change the 'export' line so the component name shows in the React DevTools Tree?

Comment: **every** component? Or just most components? `MyOtherClassComponent` should eventually show in the tree, it's just wrapped with an Anonymous one first.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a displayName:

```
const WrappedComponent = withStyles(styles)(MyOtherClassComponent)
WrappedComponent.displayName = MyOtherClassComponent

export default WrappedComponent
```

But I would expect `MyOtherClassComponent` to show up in dev tools even without a displayName, it should just be wrapped by an `Anonymous` component (or two or 10 depending on how many HOCs you've used) first.